# DD Img issue OPFsense nano install help

Tags: linux, dd

I am trying to install the OPFSense nano image to a drive I have mounted I have been using the DD command and running the following commands

```
sudo dd if=OPNsense-21.1-OpenSSL-nano-amd64.img of=/media/kyle/OPFsense
```

yields

```
dd: failed to open '/media/kyle/OPFsense': Is a directory
```

Running lsblk shows

```
  sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
   └─sda1   8:1    0 111.8G  0 part /
  sdb      8:16   0 232.9G  0 disk 
   ├─sdb1   8:17   0 232.9G  0 part /media/kyle/OPFsense
   └─sdb4   8:20   0   1.6G  0 part
```

So I attempted to run

```
 sudo dd if=OPNsense-21.1-OpenSSL-nano-amd64.img of=/sdb/sdb1
```

And that gives the following error

```
 dd: failed to open '/sdb/sdb1': No such file or directory
```

So how do I get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `sdb` is some sort of external drive, I would suggest:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1024k count=10
sudo sync
sudo dd if=./OPNsense-21.1-OpenSSL-nano-amd64.img of=/dev/sdb --status=progress
```

Please take great care in verifying that `/dev/sdb` is the correct target, since this will overwrite whatever is written on this device!

Comment: The sdb/sdb1 is absolutely the correct target it is drive mounted to the computer on a usb to Sata adapter so just run the commands posted?

Comment: I forgot to mention: Make sure that `sdb1` is not actually mounted (`mount | grep -i sdb1`). As I've said in my answer, this will erase whatever is on this drive!

Comment: There’s nothing on sbd1 it’s freshly formatted I’ve never done much with dd or Img files

Comment: Just to be safe, since `dd` will write the image "per block" directly to `/dev/sdb`, thus over-writing whatever is on this drive.

Answer (score 0):

Well, writing an image to the drive has nothing to do with its current partitions. They will get removed and new partitions will be created according to the image file.

Make sure all paths are correct and all data backup.

Unmount your currently mounted partition:

```
sudo umount /media/kyle/OPFsense
```

And write image file to the whole disk:

```
sudo dd if=OPNsense-21.1-OpenSSL-nano-amd64.img of=/dev/sdb
```